# Is it possible to have a partially applied function parameter as a vararg in Scala?

Tags: scala

Some code first, to illustrate my question

```
trait Condition extends Serializable {
    def column: String
    def value(row: Row): String = row.getAs[String](column)
    def isTrue(row: Row): Boolean
}
```

Trait Condition allows to define arbitrary conditions to apply to a Row class (Spark Row class, in case anybody wonders). This trait can be inherited by concrete condition classes, to model different conditions one would like to check against a particular row, e.g.:

```
case class List(values: String*)(val column: String) extends Condition {
    override def isTrue(row: Row): Boolean = values.contains(value(row))
}
case class IsInteger()(val column: String) extends Converter(Long.parseLong)

val condition = List("1", "A")("code")
val isCodeValid = condition.isTrue(row) // assuming the row has a column called "code"
```

Now I'd like to be able to combine multiple conditions, via a composite condition class:

```
case class And(conditions: Condition*)(val column: String) extends Condition {
    override def isTrue(row: Row): Boolean = conditions.forall(_.isTrue(row))
}
```

This allows me to compose conditions like this:

```
val condition = And(List("1", "A")("id"), IsInteger()("id"))("id")
```

, however, this has the column name being repeated for each individual condition.

What I'd rather have is `And(List("1", "A"), IsInteger())("id")`, where the `And` condition would apply its column name to all underlying conditions - however, I'm struggling with the syntax.

Essentially, I'd have to define an overloaded constructor for `And`, which, instead of taking a vararg `Condition*` parameter, would take a vararg of partially-applied `Condition` classes; something akin to

```
def this(partials: String => Condition*) = this(partials(column): _*)
```

This particular syntax fails to compile, and I'm not sure what the proper syntax should be for that, or if this is even possible.

EDIT: as per multiple suggestions, the overloaded constructor looks like

```
def this(partials: (String => Condition)*)(column: String) = 
    this(partials.map(_(column)):_*)(column)
```

However, this gives me an error

```
Error:(9, 6) double definition: 
constructor And: (conditions: Condition*)(column: String)And at line 8 
and constructor And: (partials: String => Condition*)(column: String)And at line 9 
have same type after erasure: (conditions: Seq, column: String)And
def this(partials: (String => Condition)*)(column: String) = 
    this(partials.map(_(column)):_*)(column)
```

I've also tried the same overloaded constructor without the column currying, but then it complains about missing column parameter (not unexpectedly, in the hindsight):

```
def this(partials: (String => Condition)*) = this(partials.map(_(column)):_*)

Error:(9, 67) not found: value column   
def this(partials: (String => Condition)*) = this(partials.map(_(column)):_*)
```

Comment: `partials: String => Condition*` is not a valid vararg, but `partials: (String => Condition)*` is. Or is it not what you're asking for?

Comment: Also `partials(column):_*` isn't meaningful by `partials.map { _(column) }:_*` (kinda) is ...

Comment: As I said, I'm not even sure all my syntax is correct, thanks for the suggestions. I'll update the question with my results (still not working yet)

Comment: You can't have to vararg functions with the same name (or two vararg constractors), because they all end up having the same signature. 
You can get around that by making a companion object, and defining a method there, that will call the other constructor.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out when I get back into the office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What immediately comes to mind is that not every `Condition` is on a single column. E.g. consider "all columns are equal" or `And` of two conditions on different columns. So we could change the design slightly:

```
trait Condition extends Serializable {
    def isTrue(row: Row): Boolean
}

trait SingleColumnCondition extends Serializable {
    def value(row: Row, column: String): String = row.getAs[String](column)
    def apply(column: String): Condition
}
```

And then:

```
case class List(values: String*) extends SingleColumnCondition {
    // requires Scala 2.12 to define a Condition by a lambda
    override def apply(column: String) = row => values.contains(value(row, column))
}

case class And(conditions: Condition*) extends Condition {
    override def isTrue(row: Row): Boolean = conditions.forall(_.isTrue(row))
}

case class SingleColumnAnd(conditions: SingleColumnCondition*) extends SingleColumnCondition {
    override def apply(column: String) = And(conditions.map(_(column))
}
```

You could use [`DummyImplicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745066/dummyimplicits-is-this-used-and-how) to overload `And.apply` as well (or the constructor in your current approach, of course):

```
object And {
    def apply(conditions: SingleColumnCondition*)(implicit d: DummyImplicit): SingleColumnCondition =
        SingleColumnAnd(conditions: _*)
}
```

Comment: My idea was to have each condition attached to a column, even if other columns participate in the check (i.e., "code must be L if type is S" condition would still belong to - and ultimately spit errors for - the "code", even though "type" also participates). That's why I ideally wanted to keep both constructors, to have flexibility to create And's for the same or different columns. The `DummyImplicit` suggestion is perfect, just what I needed. BTW, despite looking like a pure thought exercise, this is actually for a real banking project :)