# Explanation of scala "double definition" fix using by-name params or DummyImplicit

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have a couple of solutions to a "double definition" problem, but I can't figure what they're really doing to work around the type erasure issue.

I'll give some general context as well, since I'm probably approaching the problem wrong in the first place, but ultimately help understanding DummyImplicits & by-name params in this context is enough.

**Context**

I'm replacing parsers for deeply nested JSON where pretty much every value is optional, and nearly all data (including Int, Double, etc.) is stored as Strings.  The classes that catch the parsed values take this general form (for now).

```
case class Field1(subfield1: Option[String], subfield2: Option[String]) {

  def sf1Converted: Option[Int] = 
    Try { subfield1.get.toInt }.filter(i => lb <= i && i <= ub).toOption

  def sf2Converted: Option[Double] = 
    Try { subfield2.get.toDouble }.filter(d => lb <= d && d <= ub).toOption
}
```

This functions, but...  it's incredibly slow and requires unreal amounts of memory.  My guess is converting the Strings to numeric data out of the gate will reduce the memory considerably, and probably speed up the usage of the data at the expense of load times.

So I figured I'd do something like...

```
/** type signature w/ numeric args instead of Strings */
case class Field1(subfield1: Option[Int], subfield2: Option[Double]) 

object Field1 {
  /** the apply method I need for this class */
  def apply(subfield1: Option[String], subfield2: Option[String]): Field1 =
    new Field1(
        Try { subfield1.get.toInt }.filter(i => lb <= i && i <= ub).toOption,
        Try { subfield2.get.toDouble }.filter(d => lb <= d && d <= ub).toOption)

  /** one more to generalize the question a bit more */
  def apply(subfield1: Option[Int], subfield2: Option[Int]): Field1 =
    new Field1(subfield1, Try { subfield2.get.toDouble }.filter(d => lb <= d && d <= ub).toOption)
}
```

This obviously throws a couple `error: double definition ... have the same type after erasure` errors though.  So I've found two solutions...  but I can't figure what either one is actually doing and what problems I might get into down the road with one or the other.

**option 1** make one (different) arg in each apply method a [by-name param](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html)

```
object Field1 {
  def apply(subfield1: => Option[String], subfield2: Option[String]): Field1 = ???
  def apply(subfield1: Option[Int], subfield2: => Option[Int]): Field1 = ???
}
```

**option 2** dummy implicits

```
object Field1 {
  def apply(subfield1: Option[String], subfield2: Option[String])(implicit i: DummyImplicit): Field1 = ???
  def apply(subfield1: Option[Int], subfield2: Option[Int])(implicit i: DummyImplicit, i2: DummyImplicit): Field1 = ???
}
```

**question**

Both of these compile, but I don't understand why either one works around the type erasure issue.

I thought by-name params were only evaluated when used, and evaluated every time they're used.  I can't figure out why this fixes type erasure issues.

There's a pretty good demonstration of dummy implicits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745066/are-dummyimplicits-used-and-if-so-how), but when it gets to the core of the issue, it just says *"each call was given the implicit parameter needed to properly disambiguate the call"*.  How does a dummy value do this?

The [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/scala/Predef$$DummyImplicit.html) just say *"A type for which there is always an implicit value."*

May be a bad question, since I know how to make it work, but I'm totally lost re why either option works at all.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Scala 3 has introduced the `@targetName` [annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/targetName.html#inner-main) which can also be used to disambiguate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant section of compiled code for `option-1` looks like

```
def apply(subfield1: Function0, subfield2: Option): Field1 = scala.Predef.???();
def apply(subfield1: Option, subfield2: Function0): Field1 = scala.Predef.???();
```

As you can see by-name parameters are converted to `Function0`, so reusing the name is possible.

For `option-2` the implicit curried parameters are added as extra parameters to functions, thus making it possible to use the same name.

```
def apply(subfield1: Option, subfield2: Option, i: DummyImplicit): Field1 = scala.Predef.???();
def apply(subfield1: Option, subfield2: Option, i: DummyImplicit, i2: DummyImplicit): Field1 = scala.Predef.???();
```

You can also see that type erasure does happen.

**EDIT - Using `TypeTag` to overcome type erasure**

```
def apply[T: TypeTag](subfield1: => Option[T], subfield2: Option[T]): Field1 =
  typeOf[T] match {
    case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[String]  => new Field1(subfield1.asInstanceOf[Option[String]], subfield2.asInstanceOf[Option[String]])
    case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Int]  => ???
    case _  => new Field1(subfield1.map(_.toString), subfield2.map(_.toString))
  }
```

Comment: so let's say I now have three apply methods w type signatures `(Option, Option) => Field1`, `(Function0, Option) => Field1` & `(Option, Function0) => Field1`... if I pass `(Option[String], Option[String])`, how does the correct apply method (the 2nd one) get applied?

Comment: although I guess these aren't really "type signatures" at this point (after type erasure), but I lack the knowledge of how the correct function is applied without a corresponding type signature to `Option[String]` arguments.

Comment: Actually, you can't really use it because of type erasure as seen in the code. A workaround is to use `TypeTag`, but that won't be overloading. I will edit the post to add it.