# Scala class implementing Java interface - double definition with same erasure

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I hava a Java interface:

```java
public interface FooJava {
    void consume(String... strings);
    void consume(Integer... ints);
}
```

and I want to implement it in Scala:

```scala
class BarScala extends FooJava {
  override def consume(strings: String*): Unit = ???
  override def consume(ints: Integer*): Unit = ???
}
```

Unfortunately this fails with:

```
double definition:
override def consume(strings: String*): Unit at line 4 and
override def consume(ints: Integer*): Unit at line 5
have same type after erasure: (strings: Seq)Unit
  override def consume(ints: Integer*): Unit = ???
```

I am aware that Java compiler creates Bridge methods, and Scala compiler does not do that.

I tried an approach with DummyImplicits: [Are DummyImplicits used, and if so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745066/are-dummyimplicits-used-and-if-so-how),
but it obviously fails - `consume(ints: Integer*)(implicit i: DummyImplicit)` overrides nothing

```scala
class BarScala extends FooJava {
  override def consume(strings: String*): Unit = ???
  override def consume(ints: Integer*)(implicit i: DummyImplicit): Unit = ???
}
```

I don't own the Java interface.
Is is possible to implement it in Scala?
I'm on Scala 2.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement interface with intermediate abstract class in Java and extend this abstract class in Scala

```java
abstract class FooJavaImpl implements FooJava {
    public abstract void consumeInts(Integer... ints);

    @Override
    public void consume(Integer... ints) {
        consumeInts(ints);
    }
}
```

```scala
class BarScala extends FooJavaImpl {
  override def consume(strings: String*): Unit = ???
  def consume(ints: Integer*)(implicit i: DummyImplicit): Unit = ???
  override def consumeInts(ints: Integer*): Unit = consume(ints: _*)
}
```

Or without `DummyImplicit`

```java
abstract class FooJavaImpl implements FooJava {
    public abstract void consumeInts(Integer... ints);

    public abstract void consumeStrs(String... strs);

    @Override
    public void consume(Integer... ints) {
        consumeInts(ints);
    }

    @Override
    public void consume(String... strs) {
        consumeStrs(strs);
    }
}
```

```scala
class BarScala extends FooJavaImpl {
  override def consumeInts(ints: Integer*): Unit = ???
  override def consumeStrs(strs: String*): Unit = ???
}
```